# Attractive fixed point proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta

We have that:

$\bullet$ $f'$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$,

$\bullet$$f(a)=a$,

$\bullet$ $|f'(a)<1|$

We define a sequence given $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ by $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$.

We want to show that if $x_0$ is sufficiently close to a, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} x_n$ = a.

I have been working on this problem for a while, and keep dead ending. I know that $x_0$ sufficiently close to a means $x_0 \in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$ for some $\delta$. I cannot see how all of this comes together in the proof and would appreciate a little insight.

Also, I know that if I want to show a sequence converges, to a in this case, I need to show that for n>N, $|x_n-a|<\epsilon$ and can't see how to go about doing this. I don't know if a proof by induction would be helpful here or not.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that since $|f'(a)|<1$ and $f'$ is continuous, then $|f'(x)|<1$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $a$. Try to work with that degree of proximity.

The insight here is that you are trying to show something like the Banach fixed point theorem and we want to take advantage of the conditions to locally see $f$ as a contraction.

Comment: Okay, the idea that $|f'(x)|<1$ intuitively makes sense but is there a theorem that more rigorously states that?

Comment: Well, since $1-|f'(a)|>0$, by definition of continuity there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-a|<\delta$, $|f'(x)-f'(a)|<1-|f'(a)|$. Since $|f'(x)|-|f'(a)|\leq |f'(x)-f'(a)|$, we have that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f'(x)|-|f'(a)|<1-|f'(a)|$, i.e., $|f'(x)|<1$.

Comment: Ah, I should've seen that. So using this line of thinking, I can show that if $x_0$ is greater than a, our sequence is bounded below by a and decreasing, but how do I know that it converges to a? couldn't there be another point that our sequence converges to, or is it enough that we get to pick $x_0$ as close to a as we wish?